# AWStats on Debian Jessie forbidden from browser / unresponsive from CLI

Tags: perl, apache-httpd

I asked this on Stack Overflow a day or two ago and haven't gotten any response yet. Hoping for some insight here in getting AWStats configured and running on Debian Jessie.

Installed AWStats with `apt-get install awstats`. No complaints.

Installed Apache2 the same way.

Copied `/usr/share/doc/awstats/examples/apache.conf` to `/etc/apache2/conf-available/awstats.conf`.

Activated with `sudo a2enconf awstats`.

Restarted Apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`.

Using port 8888 and getting "Forbidden" response in browser at:

http://infiniteglitch.net:8888/cgi-bin/awstats.pl

Running from the command line just gives the help doc.

Permissions are 644. Owner is root.

What step or configuration is missing here, please?

Comment: The reason "Running from command line just gives the help doc" is because you need to give a config parameter. (`--config=domain.net`) Working from CLI with a test log file that is Apache compliant. The way to call from the browser is: domain.net:8888/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?config=domain.net Still "Forbidden", though. But it’s not an AWStats issue because: domain.net:8888/cgi-bin/hello.pl (Hello World) is also coming up as forbidden.

Comment: discovered the apache2 error log:

[Thu Jun 04 18:46:28.633521 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 10046:tid 139635174905600] [client 108.205.62.183:64784] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.pl

Answer (score 2):

First (useful) thing I did was just post a simple "hello world" script in the cgi-bin:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# hello.pl -- my first perl script!

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print <<"EOF";
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello, world!</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1>Hello, world!</H1>
</BODY>

</HTML>
EOF
```

Still forbidden. Made sure all permissions were `755` for directories and `644` for files. Played around with changing ownerships of various files to and from `root:root`, `myusername:www-data`.

Someone at Linode (web hosting) recommended using to check file permissions:

```
sudo apt-get install tree
tree -puf /usr/lib | grep cgi
tree -puf /var/www
```

Shows a tree of files, ownerships and permissions. Cool!

Checked Apache error log:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Hmmm:

```
[Sat Jun 06 05:53:24.412867 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 28374:tid 140381836453632] [client 108.205.62.183:55886] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/apache2
```

Posted a [more useful question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207906/configuring-apache-2-4-to-permit-cgi-on-debian-jessie), joined the Debian email list and was referred to the docs: `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian` then got the following SO response:

That means you haven't configured authorization for your webserver.

What you want to do is ensure that you have something like

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note that in Debian, there's an advanced configuration system which would have done all of this for you, if you would have used it ;-)

To do so, first remove (or comment out) the things you've already added. Then:

```
a2enmod cgi
service apache2 restart
```

Commented out the changes AWStats had made, ran `a2enmod`, restarted and 'Hello World' worked. Reinstated the AWStats configuration changes to `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
#
# Directives to allow use of AWStats as a CGI
#
Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/classes/"
Alias /awstatscss "/usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/css/"
Alias /awstatsicons "/usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/icon/"
ScriptAlias /awstats/ "/usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/"

#
# This is to permit URL access to scripts/files in AWStats directory.
#
<Directory "/usr/local/awstats/wwwroot">
    Options None
    #Options Index FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And there's AWStats in the browser. Awesome.